# iteration through every component instance that have tabIndex Proparty

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

i have a custom mxml  component that i  customizing   it is important to me that the  order when the user  is pressing  tab  will be   order by the  order of appherance

i read   this   answer

[Recursive iteration through every component instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751296/recursive-iteration-through-every-component-instance)
 that is very good 
 my problem is to access the   tabIndex property  to set it with running order

i need to check  if it has the  TabIndex property and if he does   set it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`hasOwnProperty()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#hasOwnProperty%28%29) method.